# Why does cv2.imshow() result in error in Python?

Tags: python, image, opencv

I am running some basic OpenCV code l, but it results in error. The code is

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img=cv2.imread('C:\Users\Pravin\Desktop\a.jpeg',1)
cv2.namedWindow('img',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.Waitkey(10000)
cv2.imshow('cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL',img)
cv2.destoryAllWindows()
```

The error for `cv2.imshow()` is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
cv2.imshow('image',img)
error: ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:261: error: (-215)
size.width>0 && size.height>
```

Why does this error happen, and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Maybe you would want to escape the back slashes.

Answer (score 6):

Most likely, the imread call didn't succeed. Make sure the image "C:\Users\Pravin\Desktop\a.jpeg" exists. (The extension .jpeg seems unusual, maybe it has to be .jpg?)

Also, as Hyperboreus suggests, please, try using forward slashes in the filename "C:/Users/Pravin/Desktop/a.jpg", or escape backslashes

```
"C:\\Users\\Pravin\\Desktop\\a.jpg"
```

Comment: "C:\Users\Pravin\Desktop\a.jpeg" surely doesn't exist, but due to another reason.

Comment: I've changed it to a.jpg but after changing it also it gives error

Comment: We can use `file("the\file\path\passed\to\imread")` to verify whether that image path exists or is correct.

Answer (score 3):

The error says that the image you opened doesn't satisfy the condition `height > 0` and `width > 0`. This may have several reasons.

Most of the times, it is due to an inexistent image address given in `imread`.

Sometimes it may be also because `imread` failed to load the image. For example, if you write some random strings in notepad and save the file as `a.jpg`, `imread` will likely not be able to load it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('E:/Images/ece/1.png',1)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem? Is it because you found the right file? If so, then it's redundant and a duplicate of Sergei Nosov's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22829365/369450). Is it because of your slightly different initialization logic? Then that would be good to know.

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked when i just changed jpeg to jpg

Try this, may be it will work

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img=cv2.imread('C:\Users\Pravin\Desktop\a.jpg',1)    #changed image format to jpg
cv2.namedWindow('img',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.Waitkey(10000)
cv2.imshow('cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL',img)
cv2.destoryAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because, python compiler cannot find the image in the place. if you copy the image in the python working directory and do this. it worked for me.

```py
    # keep image in the current working directory
    img=cv2.imread('roi.jpg',1) 
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
```

Comment: How is this effectively any different from Sergei Nosov's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22829365/369450) which says to make sure the file location is correct?