# I am trying to read a video frame by frame using python , to execute some processes on frames

Tags: python, opencv

This is my code

```
import cv2
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture("test.mpeg")
cv2.convertMaps

while True:
    # get frame by frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    cv2.imwrite('pic.png',frame)
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
None

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Itellingence Transportation Systems/Material-lab8/home_work8.py", line 12, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:261: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Have you checked the saved pic.png when this error happens? I think the error means the image has either width or height 0 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22829210/why-cv2-imshow-results-in-error-in-my-python-compiler

Comment: If the answer below has resolved your problem, please accept it. Otherwise, please comment and provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, I believe. Your loop does nothing to detect when the video is done. Eventually the video_capture object will return False when trying to read. You should check for that condition in your loop for a graceful exit.

```
import cv2
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture("test.mpeg")

while True:
    # get frame by frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    if not ret:
        break
    cv2.imwrite('pic.png',frame)
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```