# Error when trying to display image via OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv

What i'm trying to do with this is to display only the blue present in this image

```
import glob
import cv2
import numpy as np

boundaryh = np.array([[[76,40,0]]])
boundaryl = np.array([[[124,64,0]]])
images = np.array([cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob('C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\IMG_HERE\\*.jpg')])
bmask = cv2.inRange(images,boundaryl,boundaryh)
dout = cv2.bitwise_and(images,images,bmask)
print("works")
cv2.imshow("bluedetector",dout)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

When this code is executed it returns this error. I found a similar question but it doesn't answer my issue

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("bluedetector",dout)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window_w32.cpp:124: error: (-215:Assertion failed) bmi && width >= 0 && height >= 0 && (bpp == 8 || bpp == 24 || bpp == 32) in function 'FillBitmapInfo'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does cv2.imshow() result in error in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22829210/why-does-cv2-imshow-result-in-error-in-python)

Comment: sort of? I checked other examples and it should output dout correctly without the path.

Comment: You’re not checking if `imread` succeeds. It returns None when it fails. And when you pass that None into `imshow` you get that exact error message.